# Google Sheet Protect range and unprotect

Tags: google-sheets

I use the following code to protect a range from a Google Sheet

```
// Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');

// Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
// permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor("*my email account*");
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
```

where my email account is the  Google account.

I then share the sheet with some other people who I want to be able to remove protection, if they need, by running  a script triggered by clicking an icon.  The code include

```
// Remove all range protections in the spreadsheet that the user has permission to edit.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  var protection = protections[i];
  if (protection.canEdit()) {
    protection.remove();
  }
}
```

According to documentation, this code above should remove the protection.  But it does not work.  What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: For me it does delete the protected ranges. Are you sure it is not working?

Comment: Yes.  When you remove the protection, are you doing it with a different account compared to the one you used to protect the range? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Facts:

- You created the document, that makes you the owner.
- You created a protection for a range, that makes you the only person allowed to modify that range, or that protection.

### Steps needed:

1. Make the invited person an editor of your protection, so that they are able to remove it. Use `protection.addEditor("example.editor@domain.com")`
2. Now "example.editor@domain.com" can remove the protection you added.
3. "example.editor@domain.com" can create a new protection, and does not require to add you (the owner of the document) as an editor to the protection. You are editor of all protections by default.

### Example:

When the owner creates the protection initially, they should add whomever they want to be able to edit the protected range & protection as an editor to the protection itself. so you would use the example function `protectRangeAddingEditor()`.

Then if you don't want to share that function with the editors, after creating the protection remove it from the script. And leave only the `removeProtection()` & `protectRange()` for them to use.

```js
function protectRangeAddingEditor() {
  // Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
  try {
    // Create the protection (you are owner of the document & the protection since you created it)
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    // Add editors to your protection
    var editor = "example.editor@domain.com"
    protection.addEditor(editor);

    protection.setDomainEdit(false);

  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
  }
}

function removeProtection() {
  // Remove all range protections in the spreadsheet that the user has permission to edit.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
}

function protectRange() {
  // Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
  try {
    // Create the protection (you are owner of the document & the protection since you created it)
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);

  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
  }
}
```